# No Makefile.config in apollocaffe's package

Tags: makefile, cmake, caffe

recently I wanted to reinstall apollocaffe, I executed this command in terminal :

> $git clone http://github.com/Russell91/apollocaffe.git && apollocaffe

after this I looked inside of apollocaffe for "Makefile.config" , but there isn't there, just "Makefile.config.example "

I used cmake for installing apollocaffe but after installing it doesn't contain : apollocaffe.so.

I looked Russell91's git about inside of apollocaffe's package , and I didn't see Makefile.config ethier.
what should I do?
I appreciate any help.

Edit:
I found that because I wanted to reinstall apollocaffe, I used :

> rm -rf /apollocaffe

and this is the reason, but I don't know How can I fix it?

Comment: you need to copy Makefile.config.example to Makefile.config Then make sure you edit Makefile.config to suit your own configuration

Comment: cp Makefile.config.example Makefile.config